# Convergence of composition of bounded linear maps

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be normed spaces, with $A_{n} \to A$ in $L(X,Y)$ and $B_{n} \to B$ in $L(Y,Z)$ as $n \to \infty$. Where the $L$ notation denotes bounded linear maps between the normed spaces indicated in the argument.

I want to show that the composition $B_{n} \cdot A_{n} \to B \cdot A$ in $L(X,Z)$.
I am considering convergence with respect to the operator norm.

So far I have only managed to show the fairly trivial result that $B_{n} \cdot A_{n} \in L(X,Z)$ and $B \cdot A \in L(X,Z)$.

Any hints as to my next step would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: $B_n A_n - BA = (B_n - B)A + B(A_n - A) + (B_n - B)(A_n - A)$

Comment: Very nice, thank you!